queryset objects in which user has an object
App has Game model and Player model.
## PLAYER MODEL
class Player(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    art = models.URLField(max_length=150)

## GAME MODEL

# This is the Game model.
class Game(models.Model):

    this_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    player1 = models.ForeignKey('Player', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='player1', null=True, blank=True)
    player2 = models.ForeignKey('Player', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='player2', null=True, blank=True)
    player3 = models.ForeignKey('Player', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='player3', null=True, blank=True)

    p1_final_points = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    p2_final_points = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    p3_final_points = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    genre = models.CharField(max_length=7, default='')
    
    ### is the game completed
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)



I want to get a list of the Game objects in which the logged in user has a Player. This is to show that user's Game history in a dashboard so they can see past games.
This code gets all the Game objects. So it shows the history of every user.
class DashboardListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Game
    template_name = 'dashboard.html'
    context_object_name = 'tournament_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Game.objects.filter()


I can narrow down to completed games for every player like this:
class DashboardListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Game
    template_name = 'dashboard.html'
    context_object_name = 'tournament_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Game.objects.filter(completed=True)

I tried this to get to narrow down to only games of the specific user:
def get_queryset(self):
        if Player.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user).exists():
            mine = Player.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user).get()
            return Game.objects.filter(
            Q(player1=mine) | Q(player2=mine) | Q(player3=mine) & Q(completed=True))
        

But because there are multiple Player objects for the user it throws this error:
get() returned more than one Player -- it returned 12!

What I want are the 12 Games in which the user has those 12 Player objects.
How can I get those Game objects in which the user has a Player object?

Please add Player and Game models.

@raphael I've added the Player and Game models leaving out a few irrelevant fields for simplicity.

from django.db.models import Q

def get_queryset(self):
  p = Player.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)
  g = Game.objects.filter(completed=True)\
    .filter(Q(player1__in=p)|Q(player2__in=p)|Q(player3__in=p))
  return g


This is a nice solution. Thanks! I added the ".order_by("-this_id") when I realized I wanted the reverse order rendered in the template. Thanks again!

Here's the answer I came up with:
def get_queryset(self):
        q = set()
        if Player.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user).exists():
            for i in Player.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user):
                mine = i  
                for p in Game.objects.filter((Q(player1=mine) | Q(player2=mine) | Q(player3=mine)) & Q(completed=True)):
                    q.add(p)
        return q

